# Magento2: How to get locale code in javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript

I need to get the locale code of the current store ( something like en_EN ) in javascript

but I only know the store id :

```javascript
let storeId = window.checkout.storeId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add the locale code in the window object in javascript.
For me the best is to add it in the `window.checkout` object (since there's already some information about the store) so i made a plugin of the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar` class.

```php
// path: app/code/<vendor>Checkout/Plugin/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php
<?php

namespace <vendor>\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Cart;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar as DefaultSidebar;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Sidebar
{
    protected ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * add the `localeCode` variable in the result array
     */
    public function afterGetConfig(DefaultSidebar $subject, $result)
    {
        $storeId = $result['storeId'];
        $localeCode = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/locale/code',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );

        $result['localeCode'] = $localeCode;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- path: app/code/<vendor>/Checkout/etc/di.xml--> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<!--  ... -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar">
        <plugin name="<vendor>_checkout_plugin_block_cart_sidebar"
                type="<vendor>\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Cart\Sidebar" />
    </type>

</config>
```

With this plugin I can now get the localeCode like this :

```js
window.checkout.localeCode
```